# Kernel Panic (?) on new 2014 MBP

Tags: kernel

I bought a new 2014 macbook pro two weeks ago and yesterday I've had 2 consecutive grey screens with restart and another one today. It happened while opening a movie in vlc or when exiting full screen in vlc.

The error report is here. Can anyone read it? Thank you

```
Mon Sep 15 20:08:12 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800d6dc24e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800d6a3699, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000000dbdd000, CR3: 0x000000006b0b508c, CR4: 0x00000000001606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0xff000000ff000000, RCX: 0xffffff80335efe30, RDX: 0x0000000000000821
RSP: 0xffffff81fd8dbd20, RBP: 0xffffff81fd8dbd50, RSI: 0x00000000252ab7e5, RDI: 0xffffff80140075e8
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff81fd8dbed0, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff80140075e8, R13: 0xffffff8011f36000, R14: 0x000000000003f000, R15: 0xffffff8043e6abc0
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff800d6a3699, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x000000000dbdd000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81cfa03c50 : 0xffffff800d622f79 
0xffffff81cfa03cd0 : 0xffffff800d6dc24e 
0xffffff81cfa03ea0 : 0xffffff800d6f3746 
0xffffff81cfa03ec0 : 0xffffff800d6a3699 
0xffffff81fd8dbd50 : 0xffffff800d67833e 
0xffffff81fd8dbf20 : 0xffffff800d6dc68c 
0xffffff81fd8dbfb0 : 0xffffff800d6f364b 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
13E28

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BBFADD17-672B-35A2-9B7F-E4B12213E4B8
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d600000
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 22017411075576
last loaded kext at 21996892478151: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104 (addr 0xffffff7f8fc28000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 18693822674439: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104 (addr 0xffffff7f8fc28000, size 32768)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He" is doing that.

Turn it off and run VLC to verify.

I do not know why, but you can go to the [Chromium web site](http://www.chromium.org/developers/debugging-on-os-x) and look for solutions there.

Comment: From the information i pasted, can you rule out hardware problems? I have very few apps installed, all from reputable companies, all up to date. Chrome + Lightroom + VLC usually run together without problems. But I did get these 3 panics that are not easily reproducible but have happened in the same circumstances.

Comment: If it is a hardware problem it would be way more frequent. But from the log you posted there is no indication of hardware problem. It shows that the Chrome created a error in the CPU, but it might be the resources for VLC in combination with Google Chrome doing that.

Comment: 5 days without a crash, and now I got another one. Again when starting a movie in VLC.
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Comment: As said, WindowServer is your GPU, so disable the GPU switching.